# No multiple SQLi buffers in emacs 24.2.1 anymore?

Tags: emacs, sql-mode

i recently updated to from openSuSE 11.4 to 12.2 with
**GNU Emacs 24.2.1** (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.4.4).

When i start the first SQLi buffer (`sql-mysql`), all works a before, but when i want to start another SQLi buffer (`sql-mysql`) the first SQLi opens immediately. I'm not able to insert new connection parameters. That worked before.

Thanks, Lars

Update:
From sql.el.gz:

```
To set the buffer name directly, use universal-argument before sql-mysql. Once session has started, sql-rename-buffer can be called separately to rename the buffer.
```

When i rename the first sql buffer with (`sql-rename-buffer`), the problem still exists.

Comment: Could you try `C-u M-x sql-rename-buffer RET` or `C-u M-x sql-mysql RET`

Comment: `C-u M-x sql-mysql` does it! What is the magic behind this? Thanks. When you place a answer, i will accept it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not have the explanation, it is just in the error message: "use universal-argument before sql-mysql" means that you should call it with the universal argument in order to give it a buffer name. You can give that with C-u as a prefix. Perhaps you'd like to read more about it [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html).